# Object function() {location.href = this.options.url); has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jquery-events

I'm trying to pass a highchart event as a JSON attribute so that when I click on the bar it navigates to the specified url, but I get the above error. Here's the code that
I run on jsfiddle. All the highchart attributes are read from a JSON file.

```
    $(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var chart;
    var container = "summary";
    var data_1 = [24,2];
    var title = "Plant Summary";
    var subtitle = "";
    var data_1url = 'http://www.google.com';
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            "subtitle": {
            "text": subtitle,
            "align": "left",
            "enabled": false,
            "style": {
                "color": "#ffffff",
                "font-size": "12px",
                "font-family": "Segoe UI Light"
            },
            "x": 0
        },
        "yAxis": {
            "title": {
                "text": ""
            },
            "plotLines": [{
                "color": "#808080",
                "width": 1,
                "value": 0
            }]
        },
        "series": [{
            "color": "#d5d5d5",
            "url": data_1url,
            "data": data_1,
            "name": "Level 1"
        }],
        "title": {
            "text": title,
            "align": "center",
            "enabled": false,
            "style": {
                "color": "#ffffff",
                "font-size": "14px",
                "font-family": "Segoe UI Light"
            },
            "x": ""
        },
        "chart": {
            "zoomType": "xy",
            "marginBottom": 50,
            "height": 170,
            "animation": "true",
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "marginRight": 20,
            "renderTo": container,
            "type": "bar"
        },
        "plotOptions": {
            "series": {
                "stacking": "percent",
                "cursor": "pointer",
                "point": {
                    "events": {
                        "click": "function() {location.href = this.options.url);"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "xAxis": {

        },
        "exporting": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "legend": {
            "verticalAlign": "bottom",
            "align": "center",
            "enabled": false,
            "borderWidth": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "x": 0,
            "layout": "horizontal"
        }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a syntax error, you need to use `}` instead of `)`:

```
"function() {location.href = this.options.url);"
---------------------------------------------^
```

Close that using `}`.

And moreover, you don't enclose `function()` inside `"`s. So the final code will be:

```
"events": {
    "click": function() {location.href = this.options.url;}
}
```

Comment: I've corrected and used "}" instead of ")" but still get the same error. I've also removed the quotes from the function.

Comment: Add your updated code in the question. Lemme check and will show you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with passing function in JSON, possible solution is to add `( function() {} )` to your code, and then eval that values: http://jsfiddle.net/g5MHF/2/

Also, there should be `this.series.options.url` according to your data (your series has url, not a point).